# Variable template in C++11

Tags: c++11, templates, variables

Maybe I will have a stupid question. The C++14 standard brings a concept of a template variable. Is it possible to do a similar thing using the C++11 standard?

Thank you,
Marek

Comment: Make it a static variable of a template class, perhaps?

Comment: @j6t this should be an answer

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to achieve the effect of variable templates in C++11 is to place them as static variable in a class template:

```
template<typename T, T V>
T my_value = V;
```

becomes

```
template<typename T, T V>
struct value_helper {
   static T value = V;
};
```

(I am bad at naming things, though.)

Comment: Thanks. I did it before asking this question. But, I don't like calling value_helper<int, 2>::value.